# pyuic5 not finding file

Tags: python, pyqt5, file-not-found, pyuic

I am learning PyQt5, and while converting a ui to py, it throws this error:

```
Error: No such file or directory: "Disaster.ui"
```

The file name is *Disaster.ui*. The command is:

```
pyuic5 -x Disaster.ui -o abc.py
```

Comment: Are you completely sure that the name is correct and you are in the path of that file? Ensure that you didn't add any spaces, and verify that the casing is also correct.

Comment: Yes. I am 101% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the file *Disaster.ui* does not exist in the current folder (i.e. wherever you're executing `pyuic5` from). To prove this, execute `dir *.ui`.

To fix it, either `cd` to the relevant folder, or use an absolute path instead.